# Different layout for all Ajax calls in Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Whenever an ajax call is executed, I want the controllers to use the layout named "ajax" instead of the default "main" layout.

Does someone have an idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a global solution, you can create a base controller in `components` and change the layout in the `init` function:

```
namespace app\components;

class Controller extends \yii\web\Controller 
{

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $this->layout = '@app/path/to/ajax';
        }
    }
}
```

You should then ensure your controllers extend `app\components\Controller`.

Comment: In which file should i include this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if its an Ajax request then change the layout

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```